# Time change notification (hours and minutes) in objc

Tags: objective-c, time, nstimer, clock, clock-synchronization

Is there a best practice to obtain a notification when the time changes?

I'm using a `NSTimer` that checks every 0,002 secs if the time is changed (hours and minutes, not seconds and milliseconds) to maintain in sync a label in my app with the phone clock every minute.

I'd hope there is a better solution.

Thank you

Comment: NSTimer is nice solution for your task, and you can also listen to UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification (sent when user sets time in settings). However if your timer's interval is so small, you don't need notification observing

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to update when the minute changes, this should do the trick:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
[self performSelector:@selector(minuteHasChanged) withObject:nil afterDelay:(60 - dateComponents.minute)];
```

And, if you can be certain to only call this method exactly once then you could do something like this:

```
- (void)minuteHasChanged {
    //do stuff

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    [self performSelector:@selector(minuteHasChanged) withObject:nil afterDelay:(60 - dateComponents.minute)];
}
```

Comment: Modifying your solution extracting the seconds component from the date, doesn't work either. The solution I've adopted with NSTimer works but doesn't update the label instantly as I expect.

Comment: try updating label on main thread by calling [self performSelectoronMainThread:@selector(updateLabel) withObject:nil];

Answer (score 2):

Set a recurring timer starting at the next whole minute:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)        

    let nextMinuteDate =  NSCalendar.currentCalendar().nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), matchingUnit: .Second, value: 0, options: [.MatchNextTime])!
    self.minuteDidChangeTimer = NSTimer(fireDate: nextMinuteDate, interval: 60.0, target: self, selector: "minuteDidChangeTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.minuteDidChangeTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    :
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.minuteDidChangeTimer.invalidate()
    self.minuteDidChangeTimer = nil

    :
}
```

You might also want to update your UI in response to `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` for major, unexpected changes, i.e. "change to a new day (midnight), carrier time update, and change to or from daylight savings time".